# Why is it unsafe to use a generic self type in an argument?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, typing

The [mypy doc says](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-methods-and-generic-self):

> Note that mypy lets you use generic self types in certain unsafe ways in order to support common idioms. For example, using a generic self type in an argument type is accepted even though it’s unsafe.

It then mentions an example of using generic self type in an argument:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class Base:
    def compare(self: T, other: T) -> bool:
        return False

class Sub(Base):
    def __init__(self, x: int) -> None:
        self.x = x

    # This is unsafe (see below) but allowed because it's
    # a common pattern and rarely causes issues in practice.
    def compare(self, other: Sub) -> bool:
        return self.x > other.x

b: Base = Sub(42)
b.compare(Base())  # Runtime error here: 'Base' object has no attribute 'x'
```

I can't understand what's the "unsafe" matter here. The main problem is that the `b` variable is assigned a type that is not precise (b:Base)

So what is the point in the doc?

P.S: The point of "unsafe" in the doc is that it type checks well but will produce an exception in runtime. But what I can't understand is that why this is related to the annotation of `other: T` in `Base.compare`. I think It's due to the imprecise type of b that should have been cast to Sub by the developer.

In other words: What should I do in case I have a method that accepts the same object type as self as its other arguments?

Comment: Base.compare *says* that it will accept another Base as its other argument; so a user should expect `base1.compare(base2)` to work for *any* two instances of `Base` (including instances of `Sub`). But if `base1` is an instance of `Sub` and `base2` is not, it won't work. That's why it's regarded as unsafe.

Comment: Thank you @khelwood
So what should I do in case I have a method that accepts the same object type as self as its other arguments? (and it may have subclasses that override the method and need finer types)

Comment: Either do it in the way that is unsafe (but a "common idiom" according to mypy), or don't put that method in your Base type.

Answer (score 1):

`Base.compare` only requires that both arguments have the same static type. The *static* type of `b` is `Base` (due to the hint), despite that its *dynamic* type is `Sub` at runtime.

When type-checking `b.compare(Base())`, everything "checks":

1. `b` has static type `Base`.
2. In `Base.compare`, `self` has static type `T`, which can accept anything, so `T` is bound to `Base`.
3. The explicit argument to `Base.compare` is *also* of type `Base`, so is allowed by the type checker.

At no point did you specify that either `self` or `other` requires support for an `x` attribute, leading to the runtime error.

It's not really a "problem" that `b` is assigned a value of type `Sub`. `Sub` is a subclass of `Base`, and thus is *compatible* with the hinted type `Base`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So if `def compare(self: T, other: T):` is unsafe, what should I do in case I have a method that accepts the same object type as self as its other arguments?

Comment: In other words, I think in the above code example, it was the developer's responsibility to ensure `b` has the precise type and if not, cast it to `Sub`. In that case, I see no "unsafe" point anymore! Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: In this case, `Sub.compare` is an unsafe override of the inherited method, because the type does not reflect the requirement to support an `x` attribute. (And if it *did*, it would be a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle, but that's another topic.) It's considered unsafe because while the programmer *can* use `cast` to tell the type checker not to worry, the type checker itself can't determine that.